# Android TV hide/show PlaybackControlsRow programmatically

Tags: android, android-tv

In androidTV is there any way to hide and show the PlaybackcontrolsRow programmatically? (I check the official documentation, but there is nothing related to it)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PlaybackFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackFragment.html) has the methods you want to achieve this.

[`tickle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackFragment.html#tickle()) will show the controls.

[`hideControlsOverlay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackFragment.html#hideControlsOverlay(boolean)) will hide the controls.

---

For those not on the latest version of Leanback:

The [`PlaybackOverlayFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackOverlayFragment.html) has the methods you want to achieve this.

[`tickle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackOverlayFragment.html#tickle()) will show the controls.

[`fadeOut()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackOverlayFragment.html#fadeOut()) will hide the controls.

Comment: Thanks, that function is not available on PlaybackOverlayFragment, anyway I will upvote you

Comment: @SebastianCorradi Just edited my post for the older version of Leanback.